# Proof that if $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R^m}$ is differentiable then it's continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, proof-explanation

I've read the proof given below and am confused about the proof.  I know I want to show that $f(p+h)-f(p) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.  Can someone explain their process?  An alternative proof would be helpful.  And why couldn't we use the proof used in the single variable case where we write $\lim_{h\to 0}f(p+h)-f(p)= \dfrac{\big(f(p+h)-f(p)\big)|h|}{|h|} \Longrightarrow f'(p)|h| \Longrightarrow f'(p)0=0$?

---

[image]

Comment: How did you define differentiable function $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ in the class/book?

Comment: I found the problems online.  I seem to have found the same problem but with a much clearer proof in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds.  I'm reading through it right now

Comment: I see, but make sure that you understand what is wrong in your original idea

Comment: I assume I made a mistake by rewriting $\dfrac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{|h|}=f'(p)$.  The definition is the linear function $\lambda$ such that $\dfrac{f(p+h)-f(p)-\lambda (h)}{|h|}=0$, so I can't use the equivalence I wrote above?

Comment: Yes exactly!,  ..

Comment: ok.  Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much clearer proof!

---

$\phantom{}$

[image]